# How to substring one by one in one button in php?

Tags: php

How to substring one by one in one button in php ?
Example: 
$myvar="abc";
i need one button when click 1 time=display a, click 2time display b, and click 3time 
display c. click how many time ?depend on string of $myvar.

Best regards

Comment: you need to look into javascript for that

Answer (score 0):

sure you should look into javascript for that, sir.

anyway, i'll give you some codes, assuming the button has an id as "Btn";

```
var str = 'abc';
var n = 0;
var btn = document.getElementById('Btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
    alert(str.substring(n, n + 1));
    n = (n + 1) % 3；
};
```

Comment: I want to echo text instead of alert. What should i do sir? Best regards

Comment: HI sir can i ask one question? example string is abc. i want to display ??? depend on string when click 1 time show a?? , 2 time ab? and 3 time is abc. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i made a mistake.
the semicolon at the end of "n = (n + 1) % 3" is not correct!(i carelessly used a chinese semicolon instead...)

```
var str = 'abc';
var n = 0;
var btn = document.getElementById('Btn');

btn.onclick = function() {
    alert(str.substring(n, n + 1));
    n = (n + 1) % 3;
};
```

this piece might be OK.

Comment: "n = (n + 1) % str.length;" would allow for variable string length

Comment: can provide complete coding?. Best regards

Comment: HI sir can i ask one question? example string is abc. i want to display ??? depend on string when click 1 time show a?? , 2 time ab? and 3 time is abc. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

i assume the element you use to display has an id "Txt", which can be a "span" or a "div" or any other elements you like.

```
<a href="#" id="Btn">Click Me!</a>
<span id="Txt"></span>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function displayOneByOne(str) {
    var n = 0;
    var btn = document.getElementById('Btn')    //get the clickable element
    var txt = document.getElementById('Txt')    //get the area to display the character

    btn.onclick = function() {
        txt.innerHTML = str.substring(n, n + 1);
------------------------------------------------
        if (n < str.length) n++;
        else return false;
------------------------------------------------
    }
}

displayOneByOne("YOUR_STRING_HERE");
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I want to echo text instead of alert. What should i do sir? Best regards

Comment: ok i c. one more question. i want to display abc then stop execute script. how to do that ?

Comment: you're welcome. seems you must have more than 20 reputation so that you can vote...

Comment: Thank very much. ok hope you help me next question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="Btn">Click Me!</a>
<span id="Txt"></span>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function displayOneByOne(str) {
    var n = 1;
    var btn = document.getElementById('Btn')    //get the clickable element
    var txt = document.getElementById('Txt')    //get the area to display the character

    btn.onclick = function() {
        if (n <= str.length)
        txt.innerHTML = str.substring(0, n++);
        return false;
    }
}

displayOneByOne("YOUR_OWN_STRING");
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

if you input "abc" then click, it will display like this:

"a" --> "ab"  --> "abc"